# PowerShell Get-ADUser unable to return data

Tags: powershell

I'm working in PowerShell, and I have RSAT installed on my laptop.  I am running the following commands from my laptop:

```
$attributes = @("sAMAccountName","userAccountControl"); 

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $attributes -Server "10.111.25.6" |
Measure-Object;
```

I get the following error message:

> - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADServerDownException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it
>       does not have the Active Directory Web Services
>       running.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

What is strange is that I can extract data out of that server with the csvde utility.  So, the given server does indeed exist and isn't down.  My best guess is that it doesn't have Active Directory Web Services running.  I don't know how to determine this, though.  How can I resolve this `Get-ADUser` problem?

Comment: Do you need the `-Server` parameter?

Comment: What's the output of `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName '10.111.25.6' -Port 9389`? (9389 is the port for AD WS)

Comment: Yes, I need the -Server parameter.  Unfortunately, I cannot run Test-NetConnection, because I only have Windows 7 on my laptop, and because I can't find any machine with Windows 8 or higher to remote import the NetTCPIP module into my machine.

Comment: Can you ping `10.111.25.6`? Then you will have to test if port 9389 is open as well... if you are on the domain your are trying to query, you don't need the server parameter. PowerShell will default to the AD server you authenticated with when you logged in

Comment: I pinged 10.111.25.6, and I determined that port 9389 is not open on it.